# download tomcat for servlet

Tags: java, tomcat

hi I want to download tomcat5.5 But I m not getting proper link from where I can download.
plz tell me link for downloading tomcat5.5 for servlet programs

Answer (score 0):

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi

Comment: ya i have seen this site but there is no option for downloading tomcat5.5.